Setting log4j2.xml file hides existing log statements console output
Succinctly, my logger objects no longer print anything to the console once I set a log4j2.xml config file. In my Spring Boot application on Java 17, I have imported dependencies that pulled in their own dependencies that handled logging for me.
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>

Now I need to integrate OpenTelemetry into my application. As a part of this process I'm trying to set the log4j2.xml file. The contents, which I suspect doesn't really matter however, look like this
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN" packages="io.opentelemetry.instrumentation.log4j.appender.v2_17">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout
                    pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
        </Console>
        <OpenTelemetry name="OpenTelemetry"/>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="OpenTelemetry"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>

In addition to adding this file to the classpath, I've added logging.config=classpath:log4j2.xml to application.properties, as well as adding the following exclusion to the above two dependencies.
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>

Now, the logs I see are following the expected format defined in log4j2.xml but not all the logs I expect to see are showing up. In particular, the logs which I have printed out throughout the application are not showing (i.e. any statement that goes like LOG.info(...)), which is what I really want. The logs that do show up are pretty much from anything else. Example:
2024-04-02 13:40:05 INFO  InsuranceRemittanceApplication:51 - Starting ApplicationName using Java 17.0.7 with PID 86012 (/Users/user/repos/project-name/target/classes started by phe605 in /Users/user/repos/project-name)
2024-04-02 13:40:05 INFO  ApplicationName:640 - The following 1 profile is active: "local"
DEBUG StatusLogger AsyncLogger.ThreadNameStrategy=UNCACHED (user specified null, default is UNCACHED)
TRACE StatusLogger Using default SystemClock for timestamps.
DEBUG StatusLogger org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.SystemClock supports precise timestamps.
2024-04-02 13:40:06 INFO  RepositoryConfigurationDelegate:138 - Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2024-04-02 13:40:07 INFO  RepositoryConfigurationDelegate:208 - Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 10 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2024-04-02 13:40:07 INFO  PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker:409 - Bean 'io.opentelemetry.instrumentation.spring.autoconfigure.httpclients.resttemplate.RestTemplateAutoConfiguration' of type [io.opentelemetry.instrumentation.spring.autoconfigure.httpclients.resttemplate.RestTemplateAutoConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$0] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2024-04-02 13:40:07 INFO  TomcatWebServer:108 - Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
...

So things that are important but not log statements such as HELLO TEST MESSAGE from log statements I can sprinkle throughout my application.
I have tried

Adding the following, as suggested by this thread:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
</dependency>

but the latest version number I can use, 1.38.RELEASE, pulls in a vulnerable version of log4j.
Adding -Dlog4j2.debug=true. However this doesn't give anything that I can see might be the problem.
 ...
     TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [/log4j2.xml] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
     ERROR StatusLogger Reconfiguration failed: No configuration found for '251a69d7' at 'null' in 'null'
     DEBUG StatusLogger Shutdown hook enabled. Registering a new one.
     DEBUG StatusLogger LoggerContext[name=251a69d7, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@17f9d882] started OK.
     DEBUG StatusLogger Using configurationFactory org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory@31ea9581
     DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Lookup' found 18 plugins
     DEBUG StatusLogger Closing BufferedInputStream java.io.BufferedInputStream@2453f95d
     DEBUG StatusLogger Loaded configuration from /Users/user/repos/project-name/target/classes/log4j2.xml
     DEBUG StatusLogger Starting LoggerContext[name=251a69d7, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@17f9d882] with configuration XmlConfiguration[location=/Users/user/repos/project-name/target/classes/log4j2.xml]...
     DEBUG StatusLogger Apache Log4j Core 2.20 initializing configuration XmlConfiguration[location=/Users/user/repos/project-name/target/classes/log4j2.xml]
     DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Core' found 132 plugins
     DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Level' found 0 plugins
     DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Lookup' found 18 plugins
     DEBUG StatusLogger Building Plugin[name=layout, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout].
     TRACE StatusLogger TypeConverterRegistry initializing.
     DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'TypeConverter' found 26 plugins
     DEBUG StatusLogger PatternLayout$Builder(pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n", PatternSelector=null, Configuration(/Users/user/repos/project-name/target/classes/log4j2.xml), Replace=null, charset="null", alwaysWriteExceptions="null", disableAnsi="null", noConsoleNoAnsi="null", header="null", footer="null")
     DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Converter' found 48 plugins
     DEBUG StatusLogger Building Plugin[name=appender, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender].
     DEBUG StatusLogger ConsoleAppender$Builder(target="SYSTEM_OUT", follow="null", direct="null", bufferedIo="null", bufferSize="null", immediateFlush="null", ignoreExceptions="null", PatternLayout(%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n), name="Console", Configuration(/Users/user/repos/project-name/target/classes/log4j2.xml), Filter=null, ={})
     DEBUG StatusLogger Starting OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false
     DEBUG StatusLogger Building Plugin[name=appenders, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppendersPlugin].
     DEBUG StatusLogger createAppenders(={Console})
     DEBUG StatusLogger Building Plugin[name=AppenderRef, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef].
     DEBUG StatusLogger createAppenderRef(ref="OpenTelemetry", level="null", Filter=null)
     DEBUG StatusLogger Building Plugin[name=AppenderRef, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef].
     DEBUG StatusLogger createAppenderRef(ref="Console", level="null", Filter=null)
     DEBUG StatusLogger Building Plugin[name=root, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig$RootLogger].
     DEBUG StatusLogger LoggerConfig$RootLogger$Builder(additivity="null", level="INFO", levelAndRefs="null", includeLocation="null", ={OpenTelemetry, Console}, ={}, Configuration(/Users/user/repos/project-name/target/classes/log4j2.xml), Filter=null)
 ...





Check this answer on how to effectively exclude spring-boot-starter-logging and add spring-boot-starter-log4j2 (remark the 2 in the name).

Hi @PiotrP.Karwasz, thank you, this indeed resulted in what I wanted.

Probably you had some leftovers of spring-boot-starter-logging in your dependencies. The log4j-to-slf4j and log4j-slf4j-impl artifacts in particular are both bridges between Log4j API and SLF4J, but in different directions. They automatically disable themselves, when they detect the other one.

Yeah, I really thought I had excluded everything at first (from camel-spring-boot-starter and spring-boot-starter-web), but excluding it from spring-boot-starter as well and explicitly adding spring-boot-starter-log4j2 was the final touch. Much appreciated, cheers.
